# Improving portraits - who am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I am a tool for improving portrait photography

I'm half as valuable as salt

I am at home in many places, one of those is the exact middle of a popular dairy product

I'm often considered the same if only half of me is present

What am I?

Edit: Do we need some clues?

Comment: It might be a bit premature for clues, considering readers are in all different timezones - I think people usually wait 24 hours. I'm very curious about this one... considering how many dairy products I consume I feel the answer must be staring me in the face, but no luck yet :P

Comment: is it some kind of software?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[INCOMPLETE ANSWER]** But I have what I believe are strong guesses for some of the clues.

I think you are..

> "**EE**" or "**TT**".

---

*I am a tool for improving portrait photography*

> No idea.

*I'm half as valuable as salt*

> The word "SALT" is worth 4 points in Scrabble. Since the letters *E* and *T* are both worth 1 point each, "EE" and "TT" are worth 2 points, which is half of what "SALT" is worth.

*I am at home in many places, one of those is the exact middle of a popular dairy product*

> For "EE": Ch**ee**se. For "TT": Bu**tt**er. The letters are in the exact center of the word in both cases.

*I'm often considered the same if only half of me is present*

> This is more applicable for "TT", which is still pronounced like "T" in most if not all words.

Comment: Excellent guesses, impressive! One of them is indeed correct. Development of the first point will steer you to which one

Comment: Saying "cheese" improves portrait photography.

Comment: For the last clue, consider the words d***e***fuse and s***ee***n.

Comment: For the first clue: Edge Enhancement  is a photo improving technique.

Comment: @DarrenH now that this has been accepted, can you tell us what you intended for the clues?

Comment: I am a tool for improving portrait photography - People may be asked to say 'ee' to make them look happier for a photo

Comment: I'm half as valuable as salt - Indeed the scrabble answer was correct

Comment: I am at home in many places, one of those is the exact middle of a popular dairy product - 'ee' is in the middle of cheese, between 'ch' and 'se'

Comment: I'm often considered the same if only half of me is present - @Tonkleton got that one exactly right

Answer (score 2):

Edit: From clues I gotten from the comments and also from [SpiritFryer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18429/spiritfryer), I made some edits to my answer

---

Could it be....

> Cheese?

I am a tool for improving portrait photography

> Saying cheese to the camera

I'm half as valuable as salt

> From SpiritFryer' answers, the word SALT is worth 4 points in scrabble, and ee is worth 2 points, half of it.

I am at home in many places, one of those is the exact middle of a popular dairy product

> Cheese is a popular product in many homes.

I'm often considered the same if only half of me is present

> Not too sure about this one. Could it be that when you pronounce cheese, it's similar to chese?

Comment: either you're `cheese` or you're `EE`, you can't claim to be both.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I think SpiritFryer should

> go with EE. Everything matches up, but as someone pointed out, "Cheese" is used to get people to smile in portraits. However, the answer can't be cheese. *But,* any word with EE will do. Cheese, Trees, Breeze, etc